# Calculate distance between two coordinates out of 2 lists

Tags: java, android, list, coordinates

Hey guys i have a question.

I implemented Google Maps in my App and save the coordinates I get into an SQL Lite Database (I also have a Start and Stop button). Now I want to calculate the distance between the starting point and the end point. I get the coordinates out of two lists(one for Latidude and one for Longitude) and my problem now is how can I iterate through the list and get the coordinates out of there. I also need too read out 2 coordinates at once because I need the start and the end coordinates and this I need to do till the list is finished.

So I hope somebody knows a solution for this problem and here is my code:

```
public double calculateKM() {
    allRoute = (ArrayList<Route>) db.getAllRouteByID(drive_id);
    for (Route route : allRoute) {
        Log.d("Car: ", route.getDate());
        lat.add(route.getLatitude());//here I get the coordiantes out of the database
        lon.add(route.getLongitude());

        for (int i = 0; i < lat.size(); i++) {//and this is where I cant find a solution.
            String element = lat.get(i);
            double value = Double.parseDouble(element);



        }
        calculateDistance(...);


    }
}

private double calculateDistance(double fromLong, double fromLat,
            double toLong, double toLat) {

        double d2r = Math.PI / 180;
        double dLong = (toLong - fromLong) * d2r;
        double dLat = (toLat - fromLat) * d2r;
        double a = Math.pow(Math.sin(dLat / 2.0), 2) + Math.cos(fromLat * d2r)
                * Math.cos(toLat * d2r) * Math.pow(Math.sin(dLong / 2.0), 2);
        double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
        double d = 6367000 * c;
        return Math.round(d);

    }
```

Comment: Hi frnd... Y ur using two list views for saving latitude and longitude...

U can use one arrayList for that

Comment: You shouldn't use two lists for latitude and longitude. Those two values make your exact position, don't separate them and you won't have that problem.

Comment: it doesn't make problem... but its time consuming..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        //  create a class for saving latitude and longitude under any package
        private class Cordinate
        {
        double lati,longi;

        public Cordinate(double la,louble lo)
        {
           lati=la;
           longi=lo;
        }
        // set getters and setters for this two variables
        public double getLati() {
    return lati;
}

public void setLati(double lati) {
    this.lati = lati;
}

public double getLongi() {
    return longi;
}

public void setLongi(double longi) {
    this.longi = longi;
}



        }
        //define array list for saving the latitude and longitude
        List<Cordinate> cordinateList = new ArrayList<Cordinate>();


        // then inside your functn
        for (Route route : allRoute) {
                Log.d("Car: ", route.getDate());

                cordinateList.add(new Cordinate(route.getLattitude,rout.getLongitude));
                for (int i = 0; i < lat.size(); i++) {//and this is where I cant find a solution.
                    String element = lat.get(i);
                    double value = Double.parseDouble(element);
                }
    // then call the method CalculateDistance () by passing variables
    // You can use cordinate variables for setting the location object
    //  for ex: loc.setLatitude(cordinateList(i).getLati());
    //          loc.setLatitude(cordinateList(i).getLongi()); 


        // method for find distance
        CalculateDistance(Location loc1,Location dest)
        {
          double distance=DistanceCalculator.getDistance(loc, dest);
                        distance=Math.round(distance * 100.0) / 100.0;
        }
```

Comment: ask me if you have any queries on this answer

Comment: hey thank you for your answer but I am pretty new to java how can I set getters and setters and what do you mean with create?

Comment: the getters and setters anre simple functions to set values to the variables

i will add the functions

Comment: now he throws me the error the field cant be resolved at the cordinateList.add(new Cordinate(route.getLattitude,rout.getLongitude));

Comment: which type data returns when you call your function route.getLatitude()?

Comment: u must return a double value,,, or u must convert it into double

Comment: oke.. use Double.parsedouble(route.getLatitude()) instead of also for longitude too

Comment: yay that worked so now one error less if you could now show me how to pass the coordinated to the function i woild be really grateful

Comment: did you see the commented codes there? i have already added that

Comment: oh ty but he throws me an error at the  CalculateDistance(Location loc1,Location dest) he doesnt know Location

Comment: u have to Initialize the location object Location loc = new Location("dummyprovider"); then set the latitude and longitude

Comment: I know I'm annoying but right now I have an error at  loc.setLatitude(cordinateList(i).getLati()); cordinateList(double)is undefined for FragmentStart

Comment: are you using the exact line "cordinateList(i).getLati()"
'i' is a iterator variable

Comment: Yes im using that line

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, I agree that you shouldn't separate lat&lon at all. You could make a storage class for them both:

```
class Position{
    public final double lat;
    public final double lon;

    public Position(double lat, double lon){
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lon = lon;
    }
}
```

And store this in the list:

```
List<Position> positions = new ArrayList<Position>();
positions.add( new Position( lat, lon) );
```

And iterate through it

```
for(int i=0; i<positions.size()-1; i++){
   Position a = positions.get(i);
   Position b = positions.get(i+1);

   [.....]
}
```

If you'd like to stick with your double-list-thingy, you could iterate through them easily:

```
for(int i=0; i<lat.size(); i++){
    String latStr = lat.get(i);
    String lonStr = lon.get(i);

    [....]
}
```

But again, please don't.

Comment: Good answer, and OP, note, that once you have a class, then you can hang behaviour off the class. e.g `public double calculateDistanceTo(Position other)`. Then you start to lever OO's benefits.